# Is there a pytest method similar to in assertIsNone(x) of unittest

Tags: python, pytest

I want to check for None value in pytest code. Is there a similar assertIsNone(x) method? I have tried the following but looking for a better way.

```
assert x == None, "Sucess"
assert x != None, " Failure"
```

Comment: `assert x is None`?

Comment: `assert not x` should work

Comment: @Robert that should work, yes, but it will also accept `False`, empty strings or lists, 0...Etc.

Comment: You're looking for a better way, but the method you provided is the correct way (other than changing `==` to `is` and `!=` to `is not` for performance gains), what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: "is checks for object identity. There is only 1 object None, so when you do my_var is None, you're checking whether they actually are the same object (not just equivalent objects)"

Answer (score 19):

You can use the following - if you'd like to check that the object is actually `None` type:

```
assert x is None, "asserion failure message here"
assert x is not None, "assertion failure message here"
```

On another note; in order for you to fully understand the difference between `is` and `equal to` - `==`; here's a tiny example:

```
0 == False
# True - Equality since 0 is considered a false value.
0 is False
# False - Since they don't share the same identity.
```

Simple overview:

> The `==` operator compares by checking for equality.
>
> The `is` operator, however, compares identities.